# Rearranging Pearson's correlation coefficient

Tags: calculus

Unfortunately I haven't done algebra in some years, and it seems this skill have vanished into the abyss. I was looking at the Pearson correlation coefficient at Wikipedia, and when looking at this formula [Pearson Correlation Coefficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSbb4.png)

and then the rearranged version:
[Rearranged Pearson Correlation Coefficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOeY1.png)

I'm not able to see how the rearrangement is done.

And then lastly this, which I find easier to comprehend:
[Last rearrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsbqO.png)

It is specially between the first and second equation I'm unable to understand the rearrangement. If anyone could explain this to me, I would be a very happy person!

Comment: Your image links don't work for me, but you should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) anyway.

Comment: If you want to know why $E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)]=E(XY)-\mu_X\mu_Y$, the left-hand side is $EXY-\mu_XEY-\mu_YEX+\mu_X\mu_Y$.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not seeing how it compresses to that solution. I get how you find this:  $EXY-\mu_XEY-\mu_YEX+\mu_X\mu_Y$ but how that ends up being $E(XY) -\mu_X\mu_Y$ is not that clear to me. Isn't $EXY-\mu_YEX-\mu_XEY+\mu_X\mu_Y$  ? Just thinking X should multiply first with Y  and then $\mu_Y$ Then $\mu_X$ with each in the other parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments have verified what the question is: we want to prove$$E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)]=EXY-\mu_x\mu_Y.$$We first expand the left-hand side to$$EXY-\mu_XEY-\mu_YEX+\mu_X\mu_Y.$$Since $EX=\mu_X,\,EY=\mu_Y$, this simplifies to$$EXY+\mu_X\mu_Y(-1-1+1)=EXY-\mu_X\mu_Y.$$

Comment: Very nice and good explanation !